# Periodic Slowdowns During Games

Tags: cpu, freeze, performance

I am having trouble with my laptop. A problem that happens is a slowdown that occurs every 5 minutes or so (problem can be seen during games). The fan will start to speed up and the laptop will slow down to about 50% of its original fps. This will persist for about 30 seconds and then continue back.

Here are my specs:
Intel T3400 (2.16GHz, 2 cores, 1M cache)
3 GB RAM (PC2-5300 333MHz)
Mobile Intel 4 Series Express (1.26 GB VRAM)

Comment: Have you been playing for 24 hours in a row recently?

Comment: No, but I've played for about 5 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Your CPU is overheating.. It slows down to prevent itself from burning down.

Check if the air vents are blocked, if possible open up the laptop to clean the fans and vents (and maybe apply a new layer of TIM if it's not under warranty).